Customize v-modal in multiselect of vue-js
Basically the issue I am facing here is that i want to show the selected option containing flag and its code in v-modal and show it, but now when i am selecting anything i can't see anything selected, I also tried adding v-modal field, it contained the selected value of country in form of object. I don't have problem with its value but I just want to show my user the selected option in form of the country code and flag.
<Multiselect
   @change="onSelect"
   :options="countries"
   valueProp="iso2"
   placeholder="Select countries"
   :searchable="true"
   :multiple="false"
   :close-on-select="true"
   :clear-on-select="false"
   :preserve-search="true"
    openDirection="bottom"
    :max-height="600"
    :max-select="1"
    :object="true"
 >
<template v-slot:option="{ option }">
  <span :class="`fi fi-${option.iso2.toLowerCase()} mr-2`"></span>
     {{ option.code }}
</template> 
                      
<template #singleLabel="{ option }">
   <span :class="`fi fi-${option.iso2.toLowerCase()} mr-2`"></span>
        <input v-model="option.name" />  </template>
</Multiselect> 

Please let me know if anyone have any idea to achieve it

I got the answer , i just had to add :modelValue in multiselect and
<template #singlelabel> to display custom label.
writing this if it helps someone
